# submit multiple forms in a single django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a django project with a single html template. i am want to know if it is possible to pass multiple forms into a single template. I want to process the form differently for each of the forms that are passed. Is that possible to do and how can I differentiate the different forms for processing... if anyone can help, I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. all the forms can be rendered inside single . If you want to submit them in different events, you can add multiple submit buttons and give name attribute for each of them. An in your view you can check:

```
if 'submit_button_name' in request.POST:
```

If you just want to submit them altogether, use just one submit button. 
To render mulitple model forms in same template you can do like this:

```
<form>{{ form1.as_p }} {{ form2.as_p }}</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have another question. Is there a way to create a single model form based on two different models and grab fields from both tables?

Comment: No need to have a single form you can have multiple forms. I will edit the answer.

Comment: the answer work but a model form can only have one model??

Comment: Model forms can only have one model. There are other type of forms called formsets. But that is not what you are looking for I think.